# Remove NSLog header

Tags: ios, nslog

Below is a typical NSLog output from the console. Can I get rid of the bold text?

**2013-06-09 22:17:02.351 ProjectName[33584:907]** MyWantedText

I want to cut out the console text, and compare it (by diff), to a similar log. I don't want time data etc that only will produce false positives.

Is it possible to make my own console write method, MyNsLog, if I can't alter de behavior NSLog?

Comment: Use `printf`, or wrap it

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: Btw, `man 3 syslog` and `man 3 fprintf` and google `stderr` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your app put this into your Prefix header:

```
#undef NSLog
#define NSLog(fmt, ...) printf("%s", [[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String])
```

but id actually rather leave nslog and just use another logging mechanism like ddlog or so

Comment: The `@"%s"` needs to be `"%s"`, i.e. a c-string, not NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
NSString *text = @"Some text here";

printf("%s", [text UTF8String]);
```

Result,

```
Some text here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rid of the bold text, `NSLog()` adds the capability to print out objects variables. Also as you can see, adds the program name, the date, the time.

You can change for another logging function like `printf`